# NestJS design response structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await, nestjs

How can I structure the response to a GET request from an async function? I could just return an object on a simple request but not in an async function.

In the [cat sample](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/1714b51375a66ade109ea6ae5de627740af5a302/sample/14-mongoose-base/src/cats/cats.controller.ts#L15) of the nestjs repository is, for example, a get request with an async function inside.

```
@Get()
async findAll(): Promise<Cat[]> {
  return this.catsService.findAll();
}
```

The response the array of cats. I don't understand how I modify the code so it looks like something like this. Instead of an array, I would like to respond with an object.

```
{
  "cats": 
  [
    {
      "name": "cat1",
      "age":2, 
      "breed":"test"
    },
    { 
      "name": "cat1",
      "age":2, 
      "breed":"test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `await` as follows:

```
@Get()
async findAll(): Promise<{cats: Cat[]}> {
  return {cats: await this.catsService.findAll()};
}
```